# How to put AUTO_INCREMENT in id (PRIMARY KEY) in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBBhk.png)I created a table in navicat using SQL Server. but I could not put the `AUTO_INCREMENT` on the `id` (primary key). I'm getting an error:

> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'id', table 'excel_convert.dbo.mundipag_excel'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

As the database and the table (HUGE) are created... I need to change the id column and put the auto_increment in it! I'm not getting!

Comment: Can you show us the SQL statement you're using to insert data, which results in the error?

Comment: Also: SQL Server 2008 and 2008 R2 have reached end of life several years ago and are now **completely unsupported**. You really should be looking at upgrading to a supported version.

Answer (score 1):

Omit the value for id in the INSERT command's VALUES clause. If you are using the syntax that lists columns, i,e, INSERT INTO table_name(id, order_id, ...) VALUES (...) do not specify the identity column name.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify a few points, you have an existing table that has a primary key on the id column. There are a lot of rows already in the table which means that the id column already has values (as a primary key value cannot be NULL) from previous inserts as you said the table is huge.

You're trying to add auto increment functionality to an existing primary key. On the assumption that this is what you're trying to achieve, then unfortunately, you cannot alter a table to add identity functionality to an existing primary key column (and I'm nearly sure this extends to any column).

As potential solutions, you could add an additional column with the identity statement. If that doesn't suit, then you could rebuild the table by copying the contents from the existing table to another table with the primary key now set with the auto increment on the id column in the new table. However, you would need to be aware of any foreign keys in this instance as these will greatly complicate any potential solution.